# Do I need to use a voltage regulator or an overpower protection

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, power-electronics

I am designing a circuit that will run on 5 V. The input however may vary from 5-12 V. Should I use a voltage regulator or an overpower protection circuit. I have found the 7805 voltage regulator but the input voltage is between 6-30 V. I understand that when you use a voltage regulator the input voltage is has to be 1 V above the output voltage. How would I work around this to get a 5 V output from a 5-12 V input?

Comment: Welcome! What's your max output current? Without any other details, you'd probably be best off with a buck regulator or buck-boost regulator.

Comment: The max output current is 500ma. The 5v input goes into a boost converter which then steps it up to 18v. My worry is that if the user accidently overpowers the input with 12v it would damage the circuit. I was hoping to regulate the input to 5v before it goes into the boost converter? Thanks

Comment: Classic x-y problem. What you're actually trying to do is convert 5-12 V in to 18 V out, so find a converter that will handle that range.

Comment: Most likely the boost converter will like 12 V or 16 V even better for an output of 18 V: Check/quote the specification.

Comment: What is the boost converter you are using? It does make no sense to decrease the voltage and then increase it again - just increase it to begin with

Comment: @Finbarr I hadn't thought of it in that way. The circuit will mainly run at 5V it is just a peizo electric disc that will run at 18 V. The circuit will be powered by USB my only worry is a user accidently overpowering it. What would you suggest to be the best way to prevent this damaging the circuit. Thank you

Comment: A piezo will use close to no current at all: consider using a *charge pump*, especially if you already have a buffered clock signal somewhere. (And get used to mentioning(&re-considering) the task "one level up" lest getting locked into something too much effort early on.)

Comment: @user253751 I have designed the boost converter using this schematic with updated values. http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Switch-mode-power-supply-circuit-with-an-MC34063.png . Apologies but I have not used a boost converter before. If the input voltage was to vary from 5 V to 12 V would this effect the output?

Comment: "The circuit will be powered by USB my only worry is a user accidently overpowering it." How, exactly, do you think they will manage to do that?

Comment: @fKelectronicR The chip knows the output voltage because of R1, R2 and pin 5. It will automatically adjust itself to keep the output voltage how you want it - there is no problem if the input voltage changes - the output will stay the same - within reason. The limits here are: it's a boost converter so the output voltage can't go lower than the input voltage. And the chip is designed for up to 40 volts and might blow up if the input or output is higher than that.

Comment: @greybeard understood - this make a lot of sense.

Comment: @user253751 Great thank you.

Comment: @greybeard What is the best way to go about finding the most up to date controllers? I only used this one as it was a common one I found

Comment: @Finbarr Good point - I have just found out that USB is always at 5V. As a principle for future projects that may not be powered via USB. Should I implement some kind of protection in case the circuit is accidently over powered. What would be the best way of achieving this. I have a fear of creating a fire hazard.

Comment: You normally specify what your circuit requires, just like all the specs you're reading. If a user is stupid or careless enough to exceed them they must expect to damage it. USB is very safe - you have to go out of your way to deliberately apply more voltage than the device is designed for. In short - stop worrying.

Comment: Unless designing for "future production", go by availability and ease of use rather than *most* up to date. The MC34063A was somewhat common in the 1980s - the net never forgets. (USB *used to be* "always" 5 V until *USB power delivery*.)

Comment: "USB is always at 5V" - not true, but 5 V is the default unless your device actively negotiates a higher voltage with the other end. It doesn't happen by accident.

Comment: @fKelectronicR You can choose to add a fuse. It's not really required for USB devices (at least ones that don't use USB-PD), nor for anything using household batteries (AA, AAA, 9V etc). Although theoretically you could create something that would use one of these power sources to start a fire, it doesn't happen by accident with a short circuit. More powreful batteries like lead-acid and lithium-ion can start fires by accident and then it's a good idea to have a fuse, as close to the battery as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need either because you want to power a boost converter from the output of this. It makes no sense to reduce 12V down to 5V and then up to 18V - just convert it directly to 18V.

Switching converters (buck, boost, buck/boost, whatever) generally have flexible input voltages, that is, they *are* voltage regulators that will self-adjust to keep the output voltage how you want it, no matter what the input voltage is (within reason). Yours should be able to take an input voltage from about 3 up to 18 volts, and still output 18 volts. You don't need to make sure the input is 5 volts.

Some general info on voltage limitations: Because yours is wired as a boost converter it can't output a voltage lower than the input, which means if the input goes up to say 20 volts, so will the output. Also, the MC34063A chip is designed for up to 40 volts; if the input or output is higher than 40 volts you risk blowing it up (which is to say, it could break - it's unlikely to make an actual explosion). The number 40 comes from the "maximum ratings" table in [its datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/MC34063A.pdf). And I didn't see where it says this specifically, but based on Figure 7 I think it needs at least about 3 volts to work.